# Open links with the same call is not working

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

This is my list:

```
 <ul id="nav" class="nav nav-tabs" style="font-size:10px;color:white;background-color:#283e4a;border-bottom:5px solid #f05514;border-top-left-radius:5px;">
    <li class="active"><a style="color:white" href="#fn" data-toggle="tab">FN</a></li>
    <li><a style="color:white"  class="current" href="@Url.Action("HomeFirstHalf","Home")">FH</a></li>

</ul>
<div id="mainInfoMatches"></div>
```

And this is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#nav li a").click(function () {
        $("#mainInfoMatches").empty().append("<div id='loading'><img class='img-responsive' id='img1' src='~/Images/loadingGif2.gif' /></div>");
            $("#nav li a").removeClass('current');
            $(this).addClass('current');

            $.ajax({
                url: this.href, success: function (html) {
                    $("#mainInfoMatches").empty().append(html);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

When I click the second link it doesn't load the page.It doesn't do anything.Please help me

Answer (score 0):

If you hover over or inspect the link, is the "href" parameter completely missing from the anchor tag?

If so, this will be because you have spelt either your action or your controller name incorrectly.